# Doubts over x power y power z

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As ${x^y}^z = x^{yz}$

I am not able to figure out what is wrong below

$3^\sqrt{3}$ = $3^{3^{1/2}}$ = $3^{3^/2}$ = $3^{1.5}$ = **5.196**

**vs**

$3^\sqrt{3}$ = $3^{1.732}$ = **6.704**

What is wrong here?
How we getting different answers?

Comment: $\sqrt 3=3^{\frac{1}{2}} \neq \frac{3}{2}$. The point is $(x^y)^z \neq x^{(y^z)}$.

Comment: Actually there was a question, Find greatest integer less than $3^\sqrt{3}$ without using calculator. By following first approach I get 5 but looks like correct answer is 6 but how you solve it without calculator?

Comment: You should ask that question separately so the answer matches it.

Comment: Here is a suggestion for how to go about solving the question in the comments: First, take the logarithm, and study $\sqrt{3} \ln(3)$. Now the first quantity, we know it's something between $1.7$ and $1.8$, because we recognize $\sqrt{3}/2$ from trigonometry. On the other hand, we can calculate $\ln(3)$ from Taylor expanding. We do this to sufficient accuracy, and then use the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ to calculate this number reasonably accurately. I did this in my head with pretty crude estimates, and still managed to get the answer of $6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $a^{b^c}$ with no parenthesis is $a^{(b^c)}$ and it is different from ${(a^b)}^c$ which is $a^{bc}$.
Therefore $3^{3^{1/2}}\neq3^{3^/2}$